# How to Load Angular Controller Dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have an application with 10 views and several shared components

```
--app
-------components
-------------home
-----------------homeController.js
-----------------homeDirective.js
-----------------home.html
 .
 .
 .
-------shared
----------modals
------------someModal
--------------- someModalController.js
--------------- someModal.html
```

the components load by angular routing

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(appConfig);

    function appConfig($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when("/home", { templateUrl: "app/components/home/home.html", controller: 'homeController' })............
        otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });
    }
})();
```

the modals used in different components , all things are worked when the main page contains all script files. for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

</head>

<body ng-app="fleetCam" ng-controller="appController">
    <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <ng-view>
        </ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ngStorage.js"></script>



<script src="appMain/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="appMain/app.routes.js"></script>
<script src="appMain/app.services.js"></script>
<script src="appMain/app.directive.js"></script>


 <script src="appMain/components/home/homeController.js"></script>
   <script src="appMain/components/home/aboutController.js"></script>
   <script src="appMain/shared/modal/insert/insertController.js"></script>
```

I looking for a way to remove the last three script tags and load controller or other dependencies on the fly. I have searched a lot about lazy loading but no one works in my context especially when I add shared components.

Comment: angularAMD is one of the option

Comment: You could think of using https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

Comment: @PankajParkar I think that's my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the patterns from the async section on the official angular-seed repo: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/#loading-angular-asynchronously

https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/index-async.html

this relies on the ded/script "Async JavaScript loader & dependency manager" https://github.com/ded/script.js

Comment: by this way I should reference all dependency in the main page explicitly.